# Nested state does not reloaded

Tags: angularjs

I have this nested state:

```
       .state("inspectionsBuilder.view.step3", {
            url: '/step3',
            templateUrl: "../app/inspectionsBuilder/templates/NestedViews/FormStep3.html",
            controller: "inspectionBuilderStep3Controller",
            controllerAs: "builderStep3",
            resolve: {
                inspectionItems: ["lookupService", inspectionItemsResolver]
            }
        })
```

at some point when I press button I need to reload current nested state:

```
 inspectionItemsServises.save(newInspectionItem).then(function (result) {
            $state.go("inspectionsBuilder.view.step3");
        }, function (err) {

        });
```

The inspectionItemsServises is post service that excuted when I press the button.
But state does not reload.

Any idea why nested state does not reload?

Answer (score 1):

you should send `reload: true` as a ui-router parameter. Try this

```
$state.go("inspectionsBuilder.view.step3", {}, {reload: true});
```

second one is state parameters if you have fill them too...

Comment: ,what params get second parameter?

Comment: @Michael in your case it should be empty it is for state params... For example if you url would be like this '/step3?exampleParam' then second parameter should be like this {exampleParam: 'example'}...

Comment: actually it is how nested state works all its parent state will be reloaded as well...

Comment: Is there any way to reload only nasted state?

Comment: this is how nested states are working I don't think there is another way for ui-router at least...